# Spring boot POST requests are not working in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a very basic `spring` controller with a bunch of login/registration endpoints. I have `POST` endpoints, for eg below one.

```
@PostMapping(value = "doLogin")
public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute Users user) {
    LOGGER.info ("user requesting login => "+user.getPassword ());
    return "jsp/home.html";
}
```

I am getting below error on accessing the any `POST` endpoint.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

here's a git repo URL => https://github.com/govi20/message

I tried clean build, tried running application via `mvn` command. Neither thing worked.

When I replace `@Controller` with `@RestController` `POST` endpoints are accessible.

Comment: How to you make the request? With Postman?

Comment: Can you let us know, how you are accessing this endopoint?

Comment: @coder-croc via `HTML form`.

Comment: Okay. Is your endpoint listed in logs when you deploy your app? Can you verify the method whether it's POST/GET?

Comment: Can you add your POST Header and Body

Comment: you can check it on above git repo URL

Comment: The error is not in your controller. The error is happening because of your html page

Comment: What's the error? I tried to replace HTML with another very basic HTML page with `Hello World` message I had no success.

Comment: @AvijitBarua could you please help me.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua Nope. The weird thing is not a single `POST` request is working in the project. But when I am replacing `@Controller` with `@RestController` everything seems to be working fine, I am able to get the `JSON` value. DId you find anything suspicious in HTML?

Comment: I solved your problem. I am posting an answer.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare check my answer and let us know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the above case was with `JSP` pages, JSP pages were in the static folder. As per Spring Documentation, the static resources cannot be accessed using the `POST` method

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the / in the post path

```
@PostMapping(value = "/doLogin")
public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute Users user) {
    LOGGER.info ("user requesting login => "+user.getPassword ());
    return "jsp/home.html";
}
```

this should work

Comment: I don't have controller level mapping, so I suppose `/` is of no use in this case. Though I tried the solution suggested by you, still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I tried it using `curl` also. The weird thing is not a single `POST` request is working. But when I am replacing `@Controller` with `@RestController` everything seems to be working fine, I am able to get the `JSON` value

Answer (score -3):

Change to :

```
@GetMapping("/doLogin")
public String doLogin() {
//get user info from Security Context
    LOGGER.info ("user requesting login => "+user.getPassword ());
    return "jsp/home.html";
}
```

Comment: that's `GET` request handler.